# Transient Voltage Suppression diodes

Tags: diodes, tvs

I'm going to design a protection system for a 12V boat GPS using TVS diodes. I choose the ISO7637 pulse model in severity III, against of ignition pulse and battery disconnection. 
To calculate the energy for this particular application, which curve I have to use?

1. 8/20μsec
2. 10/1000μsec or
3. 10/150msec

and to derate the power of the diode, at what pulse width I have to read? At 0.5ms or at 1ms?

Comment: Power derating of diodes is continuous vs time. Not 0.5 or 1ms .  Perhaps  consider MOV 15 V 100A

Comment: I'm not talking about the steady state power dissipation

Comment: MOVs will wear out -- they are consumables. If you can use a high-power TVS, it will likely have a design life longer than your shortest-life component (likely some capacitor,) which is a good property.

Answer (score 1):

Load dump is based  on load during disconnect.  Power to dissipate existing load may be quite  small unless you have a big boat load of accessories.

So it depends. Normally use Joules of stored energy in inductive  load. .  Even a big cap on 12V may resonate.

so, energy = Joules = Watt-sec.

Power in inductive load (trolling motor?) =W?

1st approximation is quench the same current as the worst case load during disconnect and duration depends on stored energy in a system with a disconnected battery. 1/2 CV^2 and this energy will resonate with open circuit inductance of powered devices but get dumped into TVS.  Intermittent contacts giving the worst case condition.

> Time duration depends on storage capacitance of loads and resistance.
>   So the exact load dump depends on the load, not the ISO spec for
>   industry standard applications.  Your app. is non-std.

Either measure or guess . My guess is you have a small boat, so just ignition and low inductance wiring.

1ms should be fine.  (1/1000us would be my choice of test condition)

Biggest category is for AIr conditioner clutch in a car.

More details here from ON semi.  http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9098-D.PDF

Comment: Thanks Joe. With dissipation power I mean the power that absorbs by the diode during transient and not by a series resitance. Second question is how to derate the stated power capability from 1ms to let's say 100ms. Sorry for the cofusion.

Comment: TVS diode must handle current from inductive load dump. Energy is VI*t

Comment: Your guess is corect! According to your reccomendations, the energy is less than 1 Joule, so a 600W TVS and a 2,2Ω resistor can do a reliable job.

Comment: Good stuff.. Or a 2kW MOV for 0.50$ which may work better

Comment: I would go with the TVS, not the MOV, for reasons above. Also a 5 kW TVS vs a 600W TVS is not a cost difference that matters if you build one (or a handful) of the thing. *maybe* capacitance matters, but only on signalling lines.